# Deleting an Index from ElasticSearch using Id from terminal

Tags: elasticsearch, ujson

Given below is my UJSON (Ultra JSON) object of the index which I want to delete from ElasticSeach

```
{
u'_type': u'ratings', 
u'_source': {
            u'foo': u'fookey',
            u'bar': u'barvalue',
            u'fu': u'fuvalue',
            },
u'_index': u'fubar',
u'_version': 1,
u'found': True,
u'_id': u'fubarId'
}
```

I want to delete this index by passing the id "fubarId".Kindly provide me the query to delete it from Terminal

> Note : I am using UJSON to store and retrieve

Comment: In the ES terminology, an "index" is a store of "documents". Do you want to delete the full index (i.e. with all documents it contains) or only a single document?

Comment: I want to remove only the above index with particular ID

Comment: An index doesn't have an id, documents have ids. So I gather you want to delete a single document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete a single document using the [Delete API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html?q=delete%20docume):

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index/type/docId
```

In your case above, you would use this:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/fubar/ratings/fubarId
```